# How to manage picture previews correctly

Tags: c#, .net, performance, image, picturebox

I'm developing a C# software that is able to show previews for files. Basically, there is a  tree at the left that shows the disk filesystem entries, and a panel on the right that will show a preview of files selected in the tree, in a resizable panel that contains a docked `PictureBox`. Initially I only show preview for image files.

This software is designed for game developers, so I need to support all the image formats, I will use the great [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) library for this purpose. The key is that some image files could be big, very big so, I have several questions, about performance and memory consumption.

1. Do I need to thread the load of the picture? Always, or only if the picture is very big?
2. Would be a correct if I load the picture directly in the `Picturebox`, or should I calculate a smaller size image (like a thumbnail or something similar), save it to disk, and then, show it?
3. Someone knows where can I download big picture files to test my preview with really very large files.

Comment: Odd.  Rule number 2 in game development must be: "don't use large images, they kill the frame rate".  Get sample images from your target customer, best way to very assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Imo always thread a work like this, there is little point in trying to decide *what* is big; for images that of are talking about I would of thought most would be enough that under the wrong conditions (computer is spending resources on other processes, not just yours) it could cause a perceivable pause in the UI thread.
2. Without knowing more, I would just test your implementation when it does the basic stuff and make a judgement call. There is also the question of required quality and desktop resolution of the user - so perhaps this should be configurable in some way.
3. Imo there could be no better place than [PolyCount](http://www.polycount.com/forum/), specifically look in these forums:
   http://www.polycount.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?f=42 & 
   http://www.polycount.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?f=60